# Special characters in personnal my URL Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

First I'm sorry for my english I'm french.

I have a little problem on my wordpress personnal URL. I need to use parameters with specials characters like `{ , }` and `""`

If i went into setting "Menu" in my admin dashboard and i create a personnal link like this :

`www.mysite/documents/#sf-{"search-id":"1"}`

If i save that link Wordpress return me the link without specials characters like this :

`www.mysite/documents/#sf-search-id:1`

How can i say to wordpress, "please save and use specials characters." ???

Thank you :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". There and only characters, lots of 'em buggers. However there is only a limited amount of characters that are "allowed" inside a URL, that may be part of a legal and working URL. That is clearly defined in the formal definition of a URL. The example you gave (`...#sf-{"search-id":"1"}`) is _not_ a valild URL. Even if you could trick wordpress into accepting it the URL would not work. That is why every sane framework will try to convert your input as best as it can to have a legal and usable URL.

Comment: Why not use a query string? Example: `http://www.mysite/documents/?search-id=1`

Comment: My URL is generated by my plugin and i can't change it. I tried to modify it an Jquery script but it doesn't work.